# Chnage format return of DotNet

Tags: asp.net

I created web API using dotNet. It work but i got a little problem.
This is my controller

```
 WaybillDataAccessLayer objway = new WaybillDataAccessLayer();
 public IEnumerable<Waybill> Get(string id_wb)
    {

        List<Waybill> lstWaybill = new List<Waybill>();
        lstWaybill = objway.GetWaybill(id_wb).ToList();
        return lstWaybill;
    }
```

and my Models(WaybillDataAccessLayer)

```
public IEnumerable<Waybill> GetWaybill(String id_wb)
    {
        List<Waybill> lswaybill = new List<Waybill>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetWaybill", con);    //Stored procedure on database
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@waybill", id_wb);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read()) //foreach   
            {
                Waybill wb = new Waybill();

                wb.waybill = rdr["waybill"].ToString();
                wb.deskripsi = rdr["deskripsi"].ToString();
                wb.tanggal = rdr["tanggal"].ToString();
                wb.pengirim = rdr["pengirim"].ToString();
                wb.lokasi = rdr["lokasi"].ToString();
                wb.penerima = rdr["penerima"].ToString();

                lswaybill.Add(wb);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        return lswaybill;
    }
```

when i run this API,the output will be like this

> [
>       {
>           "waybill": "00000093",
>           "deskripsi": "SPARE PARTS",
>           "tanggal": "19990727",
>           "pengirim": "JIEP",
>           "lokasi": "HO",
>           "penerima": "JKHO"
>       }
>   ]

My Question is

1. how to remove that [] ?
2. how to add another information like

{

"status" : "sucess",

"data" {  }

}

Thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning a list of WayBill objects. If you don't want the resulting JSON to be an array, then you need to just return a single WayBill, not a List. And if you want to wrap that in more data, then create a type to represent that information, populate an instance of it, and return it.

Since you're retrieving these objects by ID, I'm assuming there should be only one WayBill for any given ID. Thus you can simplify your data access layer.

```
public Waybill GetWaybill(String id_wb)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetWaybill", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@waybill", id_wb);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        rdr.Read();
        Waybill wb = new Waybill();
        wb.waybill = rdr["waybill"].ToString();
        wb.deskripsi = rdr["deskripsi"].ToString();
        wb.tanggal = rdr["tanggal"].ToString();
        wb.pengirim = rdr["pengirim"].ToString();
        wb.lokasi = rdr["lokasi"].ToString();
        wb.penerima = rdr["penerima"].ToString();
        return wb;
    }
}
```

And add the type to wrap your response:

```
class GetWayBillResponse()
{
    public string Status { get; set;}

    public WayBill WayBill { get; set; }
}
```

Note that adding a status here isn't really all that helpful if you're seeing the object, you can assume it was successful. Also, the API would have responded with an HTTP 200 OK status code. So it's really superfluous.

Now your controller becomes:

```
WaybillDataAccessLayer objway = new WaybillDataAccessLayer();

public GetWayBillResponse Get(string id_wb)
{
    GetWayBillResponse response = new GetWayBillResponse();
    response.Status = "Success";
    response.WayBill = objway.GetWaybill(id_wb);
    return response;
}
```

Note that you can simplify your data access even further. You're manually assigning the result columns to the WayBill object. That's repetitive and boring. If you use an Object Relational Mapper such as [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), you can remove a lot of that boiler plate code.

Here's what it'd look like using Dapper:

```
public Waybill GetWaybill(String id_wb)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        return con.QuerySingle<WayBill>("spGetWaybill", new { waybill = id_web }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
}
```

Comment: cannot implicity convert type 'api.Controllers.WaybillController.GetWayBillResponse' to api.Models.Waybill'

Comment: @otniel Change the return type of your action method to return a GetWayBillResponse.

Comment: Thans Man!! U save my day . i'm really newbie on dotnet cause im develop using Codeigniter before.